# Error with converting Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: javascript, converters

So I'm trying to create a script that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit.
When I run it I get an error on line 1.
Please help me out... I do not need a new code I just need this fixed :/

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

function init() {
    var celcius = document.getElementById("celcius");
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementById("fahrenheit");
    var button = document.getElementById("button");

    celcius.value = "";
    fahrenheit.value = "";
    button.addEventListener("click", controle, false);
}


function controle() {
    var celcius = document.getElementsById("celcius");
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementsById("fahrenheit");

    if ((celcius.value != "") && fahrenheit.value != "") {
        document.getElementsById("note").innherHTML = "Please only enter information in one field."
    } else {
        calculate();
    }
}


function calculate() {
    var celcius = document.getElementsById("celcius");
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementsById("fahrenheit");
    if (celcius.value != "") {
        fahrenheit.value = (parseFloat(celcius.value) * 1.8) + 32;
    } else {
        celcius.value = (parseFloat(fahrenheit.value) - 32) / 1.8;
    }
    document.getElementsById("note").innerHTML = "Het omrekenen is damn voltooid.";
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ReferenceError: init is not defined
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

with(_..."); var (regel 2)

Comment: FYI while not the source of your error you misspelled Celsius.

Comment: I love that Dutch drops to English for the profanity :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this fixes the problem but

```
document.getElementsById("note").innherHTML
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("note").innerHTML
```

Typo: innherHTML -> innerHTML AND getElementsById -> getElementById

UPDATE: I tried to get it working by removing the errors in your code, have a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5bzAK/1/

Comment: I'm working on a jsfiddle, I'll get back to you in a minute ;)

Comment: jsfiddle added, hope this helps to get you started?

Comment: Didnt see your edit before adding my answer. +1 for beating me to it.

Comment: @Jamiec I know what you mean, I have that all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be an extra `s` in `getElementById` - youve called it getElement**s**ById

See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wZ5BF/

Comment: You're, of course, welcome. But if you're going to mark an answer as correct mark @bjornruysen's. he got there first :)

Answer (score 0):

`window.addEventListener("load", init, false);` should be below init definition.

Preferably at the end of the script.

Comment: Pleasure @MatthiasVerhoeven, Mark my answer if its the solution you were looking  out for :)